# Can I use Firebase Realtime database as local database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing android app using the Firebase Realtime database.

At first, I intended that this app store the user's data into the Firebase Realtime database.

But I got a new request to store the data in the local.
So I created SQLite database.
The customer data is stored in both SQLite and Firebase.

How about this?

Now:
 - The app has a button to enable/disable Firebase DB.
 - If customer turn off the firebase DB, the data is stored only SQLite.

After:
 - The app has a button to enable/disable Firebase DB.
 - If customer turn off the firebase DB, below method is called.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
```

My question is...

Is it possible using Firebase DB as only Local database? instead of SQLite?

Comment: The answer in the post above explains the Firebase Offline Capabilities. :)

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database is primarily a cloud-based database that continues to work in cases of short to medium term loss of connectivity. It is *not* an offline-first database.